# Pycharm environment behaves differently from activation under conda

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm starts a project with an environment set up under conda, but that environment behaves differently in under pycharm than it does when activated by conda in a terminal.

I am new to Pycharm, using 2019.2 under MacOS. When I start a new project, in the console window the first thing it says is:

```
/Users/philcummins/anaconda3/envs/TectonicsFigs/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=62877
```

which looks fine, I want to use conda. But when I try to import matplot lib:

```
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul  1 2019, 14:38:56) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

However, if I go to a terminal and activate the same environment:

```
bash-3.2% conda activate TectonicsFigs
(TectonicsFigs) bash-3.2$ which python
/Users/philcummins/anaconda3/envs/TectonicsFigs/bin/python
(TectonicsFigs) bash-3.2$ ipython
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.6.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import matplotlib                                                                                                         

In [2]:
```

Why does the environment behave differently (and correctly, ti seems to me) under conda than under Pycharm?

Can I make Pycharm's interpreter behave in the same way as conda (and to hopefully use ipython)?

Comment: Hi! Please, run Python Interpreter under PyCharm and provide `sys.path` output

Comment: What output do you have in the second case with `python`, not `ipython`?